# What is the best way to batch compile .fla files?

Tags: flash

What is the best practice for compiling a bunch of flash movie files (.fla) as part of a build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using cs4 then the new projects panel lets you publish and mange multiple flash movies. see here for more info

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7effa.html

for older flash projects look here

- http://www.gskinner.com/products/gProject/about.php